# How to optimise mongodb aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, aggregate

I have written a query to get all the data from a particular collection, lets call it collection A. Now the query needs data from other collection as well, so I wrote an aggregate query on collection A that gets data from collections B,C,D as well. The problem is all of these collections have over 100000 documents in them and because of this the query is taking a lot of time to execute. I tried adding indexes but I am still inexperienced in it so that didn't work as well.

The structure of my aggregate query is like this

$match --> $project --> $lookup --> $unwind --> $project --> $group --> $match --> $group

Since the query is too big I cannot post it here. Please help me out. Any suggestion will be grateful. Thank You

Comment: In general, indexes are applied on `$match` and `$sort` stages which are the beginning of the pipeline. Also see [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).

Comment: Even after that it is taking, around 10-15s to return the data

Comment: Share your Aggregation query and we shall see if it can be optimized

Comment: Like any other NoSQL dababases, MongoDB is not optimized for excessive joins (unlike relational RDBMS are), some NoSQL databases do not provide join operation at all! Usually the number of collection in MongoDB is much lower than the number of tables in comparing RDBMS application, maybe review your data model.

Comment: Reduce your pipeline to relevant information and post it here.

Comment: okay let me reduce it and send here